# How to maintain USB connection in Stop Mode

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32f4, usb-otg, stm32-hal

I have configured a USB CDC peripheral on the STM32F4 which starts automatically. I have also enabled the STOP power mode but the USB device disconnects when it enters STOP and does not reconnect when the device wakes up. What do I need to do in order for the device to successfully restart when it wakes up?

I can restart the USB device by calling the USB_LL_Start / HAL_PCD_Start functions but I want to prevent it from disconnecting and I am not sure how to do this.